# @ConfigurationProperties failing after migrating Springboot from 2.7 to 3.0.7

Tags: spring-boot

When migrating from Springboot 2.7.4 to 3.0.7, the code below is failing. The ConfigRepository argument of the constructor is passed as null while it was filled with the correct bean in Springboot 2.7.4.

I didn't find any changes like this in the migration guide apart from (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#constructingbinding-no-longer-needed-at-the-type-level) but we are not using @ConstructorBinding

```
@ConfigurationProperties(ConnectorProperties.PREFIX)
public class ConnectorProperties {
    static final String PREFIX = "connector";

    private ConfigRepository configRepository;

    @Value("${graceful-shutdown-period:60}")
    private long gracefulShutdownPeriod;


    public RestConnectorProperties(ConfigRepository configRepository) {
        this.configRepository = configRepository;
    }
    
    public List<String> getPartners() {
       return configRepository.getPartners();
    }
    
    public void setGracefulShutdownPeriod(long gracefulShutdownPeriod) {                       
        this.gracefulShutdownPeriod = gracefulShutdownPeriod;                                  
    }    
                                
    public long getGracefulShutdownPeriod() {   
        return gracefulShutdownPeriod;          
    }                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Could you please indicate if this is not supported anymore or if there is something to do to make it work again ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you expecting the `ConfigRepository` bean to get created? If it is from auto-configuration, then you may need to change how you are registering your auto-config classes (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files).

Comment: Right now it is working in 1.7.4 using @Configuration `@Configuration
public class ConfigConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConfigRepository configRepository(ConnectorConfig config) {
        return new ConfigRepository(config);
    }
}`

Comment: You should confirm that the `ConfigConfiguration` class is getting run at startup. If it is a plain `@Configuration` class then there's not enough information here to tell why it wouldn't run like before.

Comment: I checked with debugging and the ConfigConfiguration is run before the ConnectorProperties but the constructor agrument is empty when running on 3.0.7. I can by the way see that the call stack is different between 2.7.4 and 3.0.7. In 3.0.7, the parameter is given the default value while in 2.7.4 it is given a bean (the configRepository one). I can post both stacks here if it could help.

Comment: In 3.0.7 the ConnectorProperties is instanciated with instantiateClass:211, BeanUtils (org.springframework.beans)
instantiate:178, ValueObjectBinder$ValueObject (org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind)

Comment: In 2.7.4 it is instanciated with instantiateClass:211, BeanUtils (org.springframework.beans)
instantiate:117, SimpleInstantiationStrategy (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)

Comment: If needed I added a simple reproducer code here https://github.com/tgillain/spring-boot-configuration-properties/tree/main/test-springboot

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks @ScottFrederick for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is fixed by flagging the ConfigRepository configRepository as autowired as explained in the [Spring Boot 3.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#improved-constructorbinding-detection)

> For most users, this updated logic will allow for simpler @ConfigurationProperties classes. If, however, you have a @ConfigurationProperties and you want to inject beans into the constructor rather than binding it, you’ll now need to add an @Autowired annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).